# How to render filled B-Spline in a SM5.0 way?

Tags: c++, 2d, direct3d11, tessellation

If I want to feed GPU some isoline patches, and let it give me some triangle primitives in the end. Are there some practical ways, or where should I look for them?

It seems Direct2D uses D3D9 functions. I guess it might do the tessellation in the CPU. I wonder if there is a GPU way.

Comment: You may want to look at this Direct3D sample on [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-Tessellation-70afba2c).